# docker double service names

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm looking for a way making containers talk to each other

for instance i have two docker-compose.yml files:

first:

```
services:
  users-api:
    container_name: users-api
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres
    container_name: users-employees-db
```

second:

```
services:
  employees-api:
    container_name: employees-api
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres
    container_name: users-employees-db
```

(both docker-compose files are using same postgres db)

so is there a way saying - if there is already a running container with same name use it instead of staring a new one?

Comment: Not with `docker-compose.yml`. You'll have to write a script, for instance a shell script, to do the checking.

Answer (score 2):

You're using the same `container_name` for the postgres instance on both files.

You can use just one file for all services.

Answer (score 1):

I read about this, and it looks like `extending` is the best and most straightforward way doing so:

```
docker-compose -f employees/docker-compose.yml -f users/docker-compose.yml up
```

this will make the first configuration override by second, and all the services are aware of each other

Comment: only problem doing so is when the docker-copose.yml building a new image using a Dockerfile. The directory is relative to the first -f file. Can't change the build folder. eventually I used 'external-network' to share the mutual services